# Wordpress 5.5 breaks pagination in an older plugin

Tags: pagination

I am stuck having to use an older plugin, which is no longer maintained. The problem i'm facing is that in WordPress 5.5, the pagination that plugin uses, breaks. All you see is the first page.

This is the code for pagination it uses:

```
<?php

if ($data['total_pages'] > 1)
{
    $add_args = $data['search'];
    unset($add_args['paged’]);
    
    echo '<p class="parariusoffice-pagination">' . 
        paginate_links(array(
            'total' => $data['total_pages'],
            'current' => $data['paged’],
        
            // maybe include this: get_option('permalink_structure')
            'base' => rtrim(get_page_link(get_the_ID()), '/') . '/%#%/',
            'add_args' => $add_args
        )) .
        '</p>';
}

?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I have found that changing the permalink structure in the WordPress settings has no effect on this error.

I found this information on permalinks: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/ , but I am unable to make it work.

How can I make pagination work in this plugin?

Edit:
I have found that the main cause is that WordPress no longer allows paginated urls like: /aanbod-panden/2/?order=online_date%3Ddesc
It was suggested here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51001 to change the numeric values at the end of the url /aanbod-panden/2/ to /aanbod-panden/?2/

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that in the above plugin code are more than welcome!

Comment: Do you mean you don't see any pagination links, or they don't work? Where does `$data['total_pages']` come from? I don't think WordPress sets it, even before 5.5.

Comment: The navigation links do appear, but clicking them has no effect. They only show the first page. I found this: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/wordpress-5-5-issues/377851/#close which perfectly describes it. My page is: /aanbod-panden/ , when clicking page 2 in the pagination the url should become aanbod-panden/2/?order=online_date%3Ddesc but that gets redirected to the first page. The $data['total_pages'] comes from the plugin, that pulls real estate data from a database.

Comment: The puzzle continues. I have modified above code to: 'base' => rtrim(get_page_link(get_the_ID()), '/') . ‘?paged=%#%‘,
Which does provide the pagination in the urls, however does not show the actual paginated pages. When I disable the redirect_canonical() function, the paginated pages return a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution.

Disable the redirect canonical function with:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', '__return_false' );
```

And fix the 404 error that results from disabling the redirect canonical with this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552653/fix-pagination-after-wordpress-5-5-update)